# Company with ID “None” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted? (DJANGO)

Tags: django

'''**It does save the model but when I click the saved model it gives the error "Company with ID “None” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted? "**'''

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_code=models.CharField( max_length=30, blank=False,unique=True)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    date=models.DateField()
    
    #objects=companyManager()
    def create_company(self,company_code):

        company_code = self.create_company(
        company_code='company_code'
        )
        company_code.save(using=self._db)
        return company_code
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_code
```

Comment: How does it work? To me it looks like this would go in an infinite recursion...

Comment: It works fine. I guess problem is about my database. When I use it's local database I get no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I created the 'ID' field manually and it works fine.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id= models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
    verbose_name='Company Code')
    
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    date=models.DateField()


    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```